Chronic USB MIDI Controller Connectivity Inconsistency
I have a strange issue (which may in fact be a hardware issue, but I will get to that), where my MIDI controller (Hammer 88 keyboard) periodically cuts out with the following dmesg output:
[  268.044597] usb usb3-port4: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[  268.044605] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 34
[  268.336912] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 35 using xhci_hcd
[  268.642749] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0763, idProduct=0015, bcdDevice= 1.02
[  268.642752] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  268.642753] usb 3-4: Product: Hammer 88
[  268.642754] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: M-Audio
[  268.663766] usb 3-4: Quirk or no altest; falling back to MIDI 1.0

this will happen once every couple seconds, and of course as I see the output I assume it is an issue with the hardware. But it actually works fine on every other machine that I've tried it on, where dmesg simply doesn't print the EMI warning output, and doesn't try to reconnect every two seconds. Additionally, I've tried putting this cord in the exact same condition (near everything that could generate EMI). I have this extension cord that extends my USB-A connection, but again, if I try the exact same setup on another machine including the USB-A connection AND near all the EM-wave generating equipment, it still works. I have been trying for the entire day to simply get this correct. I have tried every single USB port on the problem computer and I have tried holding the connection between the port and the usb down. I have tried:
    kernelParams = [
      "usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
      "usbcore.quirks=0763:0015:i"
    ];

in NixOS, which does not fix the problem. I am running linux version 6.6.63. Every single other usb device I plug into my computer works with the same ports. It is simply just the combination of the MIDI controller and my desktop computer that doesn't work, because it seems to work exactly the same on my laptop which runs the same linux version. If it is a hardware problem, I don't know how I'd be able to tell because every single other device works on this machine. I also have a couple of extra kernel modules loaded (I know xhci_hcd is not required, as it is probably loaded by default):
    kernelModules = [
      "snd-seq"
      "snd-rawmidi"
      "xhci_hcd"
    ];

I assume this is a kernel level problem because it shows up in the dmesg logs. Either that, or it is a hardware issue. But it's hard to imagine it being a hardware issue if the hardware works(!) Any pointers on what I could try would greatly be appreciated.
If you'd like to reproduce this setup (lol) or you'd like to view what state my system is in on startup, you can look at this flake:
https://github.com/ret2pop/hyprnixmacs

Does the MIDI keyboard have its own power supply, or does it take power via USB? If the keyboard happens to be your most power-hungry USB device, and your desktop system happens to have slightly weaker USB power output than the other device(s) you've tested the keyboard with, that might explain the issue. In that case, inserting a powered USB hub in between the desktop and the MIDI keyboard might help, as the hub's power supply would then provide the power instead of the desktop's USB port.

Will try; I have to order the part first and then wait for it to ship to me. Another thing I'm going to try is a ferrite core around my cable, though I doubt EMI is actually the issue as I ran a lot of those tests. It is USB powered, but it also has a separate port from which it can also draw power. Unfortunately I have no idea what the connection type is and I've tried searching online to no avail, though I have the name of the controller. I might also try powering it through that port and check if it works. There are some available online for the model, but they take forever to ship.

Okay, it works today; I of course rebooted my computer many times during this test, but today, after I turned my computer on, it worked. My current running hypothesis is that it is EMI, but that changing the shape of the cord or its surroundings alters the EM waves going through the wire, and the inductance of the wire is changing when I move it around. So a short term solution is to not do anything and then see what happens, until I get my ferrite core. This may not be problem sovled still.
